# Can a command in sudoers file be restricted without the use of options or an argument

Tags: sudo

In `sudoers` file can we restrict running a command without options

for example `/bin/su` should fail and anything else after `su` with more than 4 characters should run. Example:

```
sudo su daniel
```

should run

```
michael ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL, /bin/su [a-z]{5,}
```

Just trying in these terms

Anyway to achieve that?

Comment: If you want to just execute in other user, you can do as adding options like `sudo -u USER "COMMAND"`.

Comment: So, you can do that with `sudo -u daniel -s` for getting daniel's shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcards in a sudoers command specification. To allow running `/bin/su` only with an argument that starts with 5 lowercase letters followed by any number of other arguments, you can use

```
michael ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]*
```

There's no way to restrict to a single argument unless that argument has a fixed size, because the only wildcard that can match a variable-length string is `*` and it also matches argument boundaries.

If you need more complicated rules, configure sudo to allow running a wrapper script, and perform the argument checking in that wrapper script.

`…: ALL, /bin/su …` doesn't make any sense since `ALL` already allows arbitrary commands. It's just equivalent to `…: ALL`.

It isn't clear what semantics you intend from that sudoers configuration, since [you focused on a particular implementation instead of a goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want to allow Michael to run arbitrary commands as certain users without a password, then invoking `su` is an odd indirect way to do it. Sudo already does privilege elevation, why use su on top? Define a set of users and allow Michael to run arbitrary commands as any of those users.

```
User_Alias target_users = alice, charlie, dominique
michael ALL = (target_users) NOPASSWD: ALL
```